# Which is a better pattern for dependency injection when you also want a "default" concrete dependency?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I've used both of the below patterns for testability and I'm wondering which is better OOP/SOLID.

Pattern 1: Provide two constructors, one of which creates the concrete dependency

```
public MyClass
{
    private IDependency dependency;

    public MyClass() : this(new ConcreteDependency()) { }

    public MyClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
       this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

Pattern 2: Base class has dependency intializeer and derived class calls it with concrete dependency

```
public abstract MyClassBase
{
    private IDependency dependency;

    protected void Initialize(IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}


public MyClass : MyClassBase
{
    public MyClass()
    {
       Initialize(new ConcreteDependency());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest neither. If you are using DI then I would remove all of your above constructors which lack parameters. If possible, your classes should not mention `ConcreteDependency` at all. The **only** thing that should know about `ConcreteDependency` is your IoC container.

Comment: You also mentioned *testability*. In that case your unit test should be responsible for injecting the concrete classes (or `mocks` for a more implementation-agnostic testing)

Comment: @NPras The unit tests would the second constructor in Pattern1 or the base class in Pattern 2

Comment: Can you talk us through why you aren't doing what I suggested in my first comment? Why do you feel the need for two constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both provided examples exibit the **Control Freak** anti-pattern, as described in [Dependency Injection, Second Edition Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl).

The **Control Freak** anti-pattern occurs:

> every time you depend on a **Volatile Dependency** in any place other than a [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). It's a violation of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

In the first example, even though `MyClass` uses the `IDependency` abstraction, it drags along a reference to the concrete `ConcreteDependency` component, causing the two classes to be *tightly coupled*.

This same tight coupling happens in your second example, and this is effectively the same anti-pattern. Furthermore, the second example even uses an `Initialize` method to apply a dependency to an already created instance of `MyClassBase`. This causes [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/), which is a code smell on its own.

A proper solution prevents cause tight coupling and Temporal Coupling, which means you use **Constructor Injection** and define *only a single constructor*:

```
public MyClass
{
    private IDependency dependency;

    public MyClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
       this.dependency = dependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("dependency");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the second half of the question, "_...when you also want a default concrete dependency?_"

Comment: @jaco0646: It does, because the answer is still the same. You inject that "default" dependency in through the consumer's single public constructor, like you would with any other dependency.

Comment: @Steven Let's say the dependency is `IHttpClient`. Practically everyone who uses my class will be pass in a `new HttpClient()`. Now I'm sure that `HttpClient` has some dependency, say `ISomething`, so everyone who creates an `HttpClient` will do `new HttpClient(new ConcreteSomething())` and it becomes an infinite series of concrete things that someone needs to create in order to use my class.

Comment: If `MyClass` requires an `IHttpClient`, you pass that dependency in through its ctor. Consumers of `MyClass` should not create `MyClass`, but have it injected into their ctor. This pushes the responsibility of creating such class up to a single place in the application, called [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This means that there is only a single location, and possibly _a single block of code_ that creates `new MyClass(new HttpClient(new ConcreteSomething())`. It prevents code duplication and maximizes flexibility and maintainability.

Comment: Not every time we want to maximize flexibility. Flexibily comes with cost: complexicty. I would start with simple design and gradually add more flexibility/complexity when required. Yes, it's very important to know to create flexibile design, but knowing how to make a trade-off is more important.

Comment: Martin Fowler had an interesting talk about Flexibility and Complexity: https://www.artima.com/intv/flexplex2.html

Comment: We need to separate 2 different types of dependencies: Stable and Volatile. Stable dependencies are types that can be depended upon directly, while Volatile Dependencies are the types that we wish to hide behind abstractions, in order to mock, decoratore, replace, or intercept. Volatile Dependencies are the focal point of DI. As OP wishes to hide `ConcreteDependency` behind an abstraction and provide it from the outside, it is clearly a _Volatile Dependency_ (from the perspective of `MyClass`). In other words, as `ConcreteDependency` is _volatile_, we need to apply good DI patterns.

Comment: An elaborate discussion about this can be found in [this book](https://manning.com/seemann2) by Mark Seemann (and myself). It describes when to provide abstractions to increase flexibility and increase maintainability, and when _not_ to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The downside with your two patterns is that they may break the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle): `MyClass` is a more abstract thing, but knows about `ConcreteDependency` which is a more concrete thing. Indeed:

1. Wherever you reuse the `MyClass` class, the `ConcreteDependency` class must be available.
2. Moreover, if you need to change `ConcreteDependency` to `ConcreteDependency2`, then your `MyClass` class must be changed, which is not good in some situations, for example: there are clients of `MyClass` who never use that default constructor.

Not to mention that, pattern #2 may make your objects in an unexpected state because the derived classes may forget to call the `Initialize` method, unless your documentation is very good.

I propose the use of Factory Pattern:

```
class Factory {
    public MyClass createDefault() {
        return new MyClass(new ConcreteDependency());
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'll want to be able to inject such a Factory with different concrete implementations. So better to define an IFactory<MyClass> or IMyClassFactory interface.

Comment: I agree with @RyanPierceWilliams. Your answer started very strong, but your _Concrete Factory_ solution still causes strong coupling. This is caused by the fact that dependencies are transitive. This means that since `Factory` depends on `MyClass` and `ConcreteDependency` any consumer of `Factory` depends implicitly on `MyClass` and `ConcreteDependency` as well. Although there's nothing inherently wrong with using a factory, a _Concrete Factory_, however, does not solve the problem of _tight coupling_.

Comment: It does solve the problem of tight coupling for the clients (of MyClass) which do not need the default constructor. Of course you guys could go further by making the factory more abstract. It’s ok but I would stop with a concrete factory if I don’t need more flexible but more complex design.

Comment: The problem is that if one were to use the Factory class as currently written above, there is no means of injecting an alternative factory implementation for MyClass. The createDefault() function isn't even virtual so you can't use inheritance to override it. And that is the entire point behind DI: it allows you to swap out alternative concrete implementations of your dependencies without refactoring your code.

Comment: Given current situation, we don't need such a high flexibility. We just need to separate the two ways of instancing `MyClass` into two different places (`MyClass` and `Factory`). So that while the code of `MyClass` is pure, clients who want to create `MyClass` with default concrete dependency still can do the task by using the Factory. Whether they need an abstract or concrete Factory is another story.